# How to avoid redundancy when sending commands via pexpect?

Tags: python, pexpect

I have a python's pexpect code where it sends some commands listed in a file.

Say I store some commands in a file named `commandbase`

```
ls -l /dev/
ls -l /home/ramana
ls -l /home/ramana/xyz
ls -l /home/ramana/xxx
ls -l /home/ramana/xyz/abc
ls -l /home/ramana/xxx/def
ls -l /home/dir/
```

and so on.

Observe here that after `/` I have `dev` and `home` as variables. If I'm in `home` again `ramana` and `dir` are as variables. If enter into into `ramana` there are again `xyz` and `xxx`. So basically it is of the form

```
ls -l /variable1/variable2/variable3/
```

and so on. Here I need to build a tree for every variable and its specific secondary variables.

Now I should have a list/array/file where I will store first variable and its secondary variables in another list and so on.

So I need a function like this

In the main script

```
for line in database:
             child.sendline(line+"\r")
             child.expect("\$",timeout)
```

The data base file should be something like:

```
 def commands():
        return "ls -l <some variable>/<second variable and so on>"
```

This function should return all commands with all the combinations

How do I return variable commands here instead of defining all the commands? Is it possible with arrays or lists?

**[EDIT] Editing as it is less clear. Hope I'm clear this time**

Comment: So to clarify, you want to iterate a list of strings and return each string with something prepended?

Comment: the title seems unrelated to your question in the body. Look at `itertools.product(variable1_list, variable2_list, variable3_list)`. Why do you mention `pexpect` here at all? Your question is not clear: specify what is your actual input (provide a short sample), expected output, what do you see instead with your current code? [Create a minimal code example that demonstrates the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Well I'm using `pexpect` to send commands to a remote machine. These commands can be repetitive and variable as well @J.F.Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirements are a little more complicated than it appears at first glance. Below I have adopted a convention to use lists `[...]` to indicate things to concatenate, and tuples `(...)` for things to choose from, i.e. optionals.

Your list of path names can now be expressed as this:-

```
database = (
    'dev',
    ['home', (
            'dir',
            ['ramana', (
                    '',
                    ['xyz', (
                            '',
                            'abc'
                        )
                    ],
                    ['xxx', (
                            '',
                            'def'
                        )
                    ]
                   )
            ]
         )
    ]
)
```

The above syntax avoids redundancy as much as possible. The whitespace is not necessary but helps here to illustrate which parts are on the same nested level.

Next we need a way to transform this into a list of commands:-

```
def permute(prefix, tree):
    def flatten(branch):
        #print 'flatten', branch
        results = [ ]
        if type(branch) is list:
            parts = [ ]
            for part in branch:
                if type(part) is basestring:
                    if part:
                        parts.append([part])
                else:
                    parts.append(flatten(part))

            index = map(lambda x: 0, parts)
            count = map(len, parts)
            #print 'combining', parts, index, count
            while True:
                line = map(lambda i: parts[i][index[i]],
                       range(len(parts)))
                line = '/'.join(line)
                #print '1:', line
                results.append( line )
                curIndex = len(parts)-1
                while curIndex >= 0:
                    index[curIndex] += 1
                    if index[curIndex] < count[curIndex]:
                        break
                    index[curIndex] = 0
                    curIndex -= 1
                if curIndex < 0:
                    break
        elif type(branch) is tuple:
            for option in branch:
                if type(option) is basestring:
                    if len(option):
                        #print '2:', option
                        results.append( option )
                else:
                    results.extend(flatten(option))
        else:
            #print '3:', branch
            results.append( branch )
        return results

    return map(lambda x: prefix + x, flatten(tree))
```

So now if we call `permute('ls -l /', database)` it returns the following list:-

```
[
    'ls -l /dev', 
    'ls -l /home/dir', 
    'ls -l /home/ramana/', 
    'ls -l /home/ramana/xyz/', 
    'ls -l /home/ramana/xyz/abc', 
    'ls -l /home/ramana/xxx/', 
    'ls -l /home/ramana/xxx/def'
]
```

From here it is now trivial to write these strings to a file named `commandbase` or execute it line by line.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a list comprehension...

```
paths = ['/dev/', '/dev/ramana/', ...]
command = 'ls -l'
commandsandpaths = [command + ' ' + x for x in paths]
```

`commandsandpaths` will be a list with...

```
ls -l /dev/
ls -l /dev/ramana/
```

Personally, I prefer to use string formatting rather than string concatenation...

```
commandsandpaths = ['{0} {1}'.format(command, x) for x in paths]
```

But it may be less readable if you're not familiar with the syntax

Comment: Observe that there are variables in paths as well.

Comment: @RamanaReddy Where? Or are you saying that part of the paths is supposed to be variable? If so, how is that in any way clear since `/home/ramana/xxx` is a perfectly valid path name, especially when being used as an example... Can you please edit your question to show the input data you actually have?

Comment: Edited as you said. Am I clear now? I actually have hundreds of commands to send. So instead of defining each and every command separately I need a function to return the commands with possible combinations

Comment: Thanks Ramana, that's helpful. I'm just walking out the door to go visit family over Christmas but will try to have another look if I get time

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what these variables of which you speak are.  They look like path segments to me.

Assuming you have a tree data structure consisting of nodes where each node is a tuple of a path segment, and a list of subtrees:

```
tree = [
    ('dev', []),
    ('home', [
        ('ramana', [
            ('xyz', [
                ('abc', []),
            ]),
            ('xxx', [
                ('def', []),
            ]),
        ]),
        ('dir', []),
    ]),
]
```

You can write a recursive generator function to walk the tree to generate all paths:

```
import os
import os.path

def walk_tree(tree):
    for name, subtree in tree:
        yield name
        for path in walk_tree(subtree):
            yield os.path.join(name, path)
```

You can then generate all commands:

```
commands = ['ls -l {path}'.format(path=os.sep + path) for path in walk_tree(tree)]
```

Note, this code is not the database, it is code that can generate the database.  Also, the code shown walks the tree in a depth-first order, which is different from the order you show (which appears to be some combination of depth-first and breadth-first).

Comment: Thank you @pat . This is helpful!!